# Do a preload of a website like teambox website

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to a preload in jQuery like [teambox](http://teambox.com/) website does?

I ask because I have a web application and my first page has a lot of scripts to load and the page appears ugly for 2-4 seconds as they load, so I need a preload.  Does someone know of a plugin?

Comment: If you look at their code you'll see that the page is loaded via AJAX so the thing you see when you first go there is much smaller, yours could just be the loading gif. 

However, what is the nature of the scripts you are running? Are they manipulating the DOM?

Comment: I'm not an expert with AJAX , so if you can help me it would be very appreciated =)   thx ! :)

Comment: No problem, but does your script manipulate your front page, it effects the answer a little bit

Comment: yes I have a big script.js file who affect the loading of the front page

Comment: careful with loading too much stuff ... this is one of the reasons for flash dying

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a simple loading screen that calls another HTML document that contains your webpage:

```
$(function () {
    $.get('real-page.html', function (serverResponse) {
        $('#container').fadeOut(350, function () {
            $(this).html(serverResponse).fadeIn(350);
        });
    });
});
```

This will request your code when the `document.ready` event fires and when the response is returned from the server this code will fade-out a "container" element, replace it's HTML with the response from the server, and then fade-back-in.

If you want to load a bunch of external JS files you can do this:

```
$(function () {
    var scripts  = ['/js/script1.js', '/js/script2.js', '/js/script3.js'],//create an array of scripts to get
        len      = scripts.length,//cache the length of the scripts array
        jqXHR    = [],//setup array to store jqXHR objects for AJAX requests
        html_str = '';//setup string to store HTML

    //request HTML from server and save it to variable for later use
    jqXHR.push($.get('real-page.html', function (serverResponse) {
        html_str = serverResponse;
    }));

    //iterate through the scripts array requesting each one
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        jqXHR.push($.getScript(scripts[i]));
    }

    //when all the jqXHR objects resolve then add the HTML to the DOM
    $.when(jqXHR).then(function () {
        $('#container').fadeOut(350, function () {
            $(this).html(html_str).fadeIn(350);
        });
    });
});
```

Note: you can see all the `jqXHR.push()` statements, they add the jqXHR object to an array for each AJAX request so we can make sure each of them has resolved before doing any more work.

Another-note: Make sure your server is compressing your JS files before sending them to the browser. Also if you don't, minify your production code. Here is a great tool to minify: http://htmlcompressor.com/compressor.html

Comment: This is what I was going to put, however, if the page you load via ajax has script that manipulates the DOM of that newly loaded page then this may need a little refinement

Comment: @eyaka1 I added an example of loading scripts separately from the HTML.

Comment: @Jasper  So, I suppose I can only put the header and footer on my  index.php , and put all my container on real-page.html ? And I suppose I don't need to put all my script inside the real-page.html page ?

Comment: @user1029834 What's your question?